# Get external storage path for android app in unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to share an image on whatsapp from the Unity3d app I have created. The image is stored in sdcard and I am not able to get the path of that image.

I am trying:

```
//instantiate the class Intent
AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");

//instantiate the object Intent
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

//call setAction setting ACTION_SEND as parameter
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));

//instantiate the class Uri
AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");

//instantiate the object Uri with the parse of the url's file
AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse","file:///sdcard/expl.jpg");

//call putExtra with the uri object of the file
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);

//set the type of file
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/jpeg");

//instantiate the class UnityPlayer
AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

//instantiate the object currentActivity
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

//call the activity with our Intent
currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

I think the app is not able to find the path of the image given "file:///sdcard/exp1.jpg". Can anyone help me to find the path of the external storage device in my phone?

Comment: what you get when share intent blank or error of read external?

Comment: Yea, it's probably bad pathing.